# What is the scale at which hyper ledger fabric has been deployed?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am looking for information on how many peer nodes , ordering nodes and CA servers are required to handle 1 million transactions per minute. Which deployment strategy is helpful. Docker Swarm or Kubernetes - which one is ideal to use to provide scaling and extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

The scaling of Hyperledger fabric depends on the chosen consensus method. The consensus methods that support Byzantine Fault Tolerance can handle transactions <1000 per seconds for <20 nodes. For more number of transactions or more number of nodes, other non-BFT consensus methods can be chosen. However, these other consensus methods cannot guarantee the correctness of transactions as guaranteed by the former.